# Time series: Combining trended and periodic series

Tags: time-series, heteroscedasticity, vector-autoregression, seasonality, cointegration

I have a set of strongly trended time series that are cointegrated (and I think heteroskedastic), and a a strongly periodic but not obviously trended variable that seems to explain some of the variation in my trended series. I am trying to forecast the former. The periodic variable is not seasonal in the usual sense, but rather subject to very short, sharp downward spikes (to zero) at regular intervals.

Based on the idea that it is just the relative highs and lows in the periodic variable that matters, I converted it into Z-scores, and the resulting variable is highly significant in several differernt time series models such as AR distributed Lag, a VECM, and several models in differences in the logs (which are no longer trended).

However, it seems to me that I have a look-ahead problem with the Z-scores because the mean and varience are calculated over the whole period when I am fitting the data. Is there a different standard transform used in cases like this, or an accepted alternative approach to modeling when the variables are integrated to different orders?